# How to support ES7 in ESLint

Tags: webpack, eslint, ecmascript-2016

I have a project setup with WebPack to use ESLint and I'm wanting to use ES7 for the inline bind operator `::`. Currently I'm getting the parse errors shown below

```
/Users/ryanvice/Documents/Code/pluralsight-redux-starter/src/components/project/ProjectsPage.js (1/0)
  ✖  7:27  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

/Users/ryanvice/Documents/Code/pluralsight-redux-starter/src/routes.js (2/2)
  ✖  6:26  Parse errors in imported module './components/project/ProjectsPage': Unexpected token : (7:27)  import/namespace
  ✖  6:26  Parse errors in imported module './components/project/ProjectsPage': Unexpected token : (7:27)  import/default
  !  6:26  Parse errors in imported module './components/project/ProjectsPage': Unexpected token : (7:27)  import/no-named-as-default
  !  6:26  Parse errors in imported module './components/project/ProjectsPage': Unexpected token : (7:27)  import/no-named-as-default-member

✖ 3 errors ! 2 warnings (4:45:40 PM)
```

using the following `.eslintrc` configuration which include `"ecmaVersion": 7`

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 7,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-var": 1,
    "semi": [1, "always"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0,
    "jsx-quotes": 1,
    "react/display-name": [ 1, {"ignoreTranspilerName": false }],
    "react/forbid-prop-types": [1, {"forbid": ["any"]}],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-key": 1,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
    "react/no-set-state": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/require-extension": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/sort-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Inline bind operator `::` is not part of ES7. It's a stage 0 proposal currently. With the speed proposals have been moving, it might make it to ES10 or 11...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you are using Babel, you probably want to use [babel-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint) as your ESLint parser (`"parser": "babel-eslint",`).

Comment: Sounds like missing Babel config (preset env). Better open a separate question for that with more information.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.eslintrc.json`:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2016
},
```

Source: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

> ecmaVersion - set to 3, 5 (default), 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10 to specify the version of ECMAScript syntax you want to use. You can also set to 2015 (same as 6), 2016 (same as 7), 2017 (same as 8), 2018 (same as 9), or 2019 (same as 10) to use the year-based naming.