# Eslint in Visual Studio 2017 fails when the JS file contains `async` or `const`

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-2017, eslint

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and eslint 2.0 (I assume), which is built into Visual Studio.

Eslint works fine except when the JS file contains ES6 features such as `async` and `const`. In this case, the `Error List` window in Visual Studio remains empty and there are no eslint messages displayed. It seems that eslint just fails silently when it stumbles upon a file with those keywords.

Eslint must support ES6 and I also enabled ES6 in the `.eslintrc` file.

I am not sure how to see the output from eslint to see if there's any error, because Visual Studio runs it in the background.

How do I run eslint in Visual Studio when my JS file contains ES6 features?

Here's my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  },

  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "modules": true,
    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
  },

  "env": {
    "browser": false,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },

  "plugins": [
    "standard"
  ],

  "globals": {
    "document": false,
    "navigator": false,
    "window": false
  },

  "rules": {
    "accessor-pairs": 2,
    "arrow-spacing": [
      2,
      {
        "before": true,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "block-spacing": [ 2, "always" ],
    "brace-style": [
      2,
      "1tbs",
      { "allowSingleLine": true }
    ],
    "comma-dangle": [ 2, "always-multiline" ],
    "comma-spacing": [
      2,
      {
        "before": false,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "comma-style": [ 2, "last" ],
    "constructor-super": 2,
    "curly": [ 2, "multi-line" ],
    "dot-location": [ 2, "property" ],
    "eol-last": 0,
    "eqeqeq": [ 2, "allow-null" ],
    "generator-star-spacing": [
      2,
      {
        "before": true,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "handle-callback-err": [ 2, "^(err|error)$" ],
    "indent": [
      2,
      2,
      { "SwitchCase": 1 }
    ],
    "key-spacing": [
      2,
      {
        "beforeColon": false,
        "afterColon": true
      }
    ],
    "keyword-spacing": [
      2,
      {
        "before": true,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "new-cap": [
      2,
      {
        "newIsCap": true,
        "capIsNew": false
      }
    ],
    "new-parens": 2,
    "no-array-constructor": 2,
    "no-caller": 2,
    "no-class-assign": 2,
    "no-cond-assign": 2,
    "no-const-assign": 2,
    "no-control-regex": 2,
    "no-debugger": 2,
    "no-delete-var": 2,
    "no-dupe-args": 2,
    "no-dupe-class-members": 2,
    "no-dupe-keys": 2,
    "no-duplicate-case": 2,
    "no-empty-character-class": 2,
    "no-labels": [
      2,
      {
        "allowLoop": false,
        "allowSwitch": true
      }
    ],
    "no-eval": 2,
    "no-ex-assign": 2,
    "no-extend-native": 2,
    "no-extra-bind": 2,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 2,
    "no-extra-parens": [ 2, "functions" ],
    "no-fallthrough": 2,
    "no-floating-decimal": 2,
    "no-func-assign": 2,
    "no-implied-eval": 2,
    "no-inner-declarations": [ 2, "functions" ],
    "no-invalid-regexp": 2,
    "no-irregular-whitespace": 2,
    "no-iterator": 2,
    "no-label-var": 2,
    "no-lone-blocks": 2,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 2,
    "no-multi-spaces": 2,
    "no-multi-str": 2,
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
      2,
      { "max": 1 }
    ],
    "no-native-reassign": 2,
    "no-negated-in-lhs": 2,
    "no-new": 2,
    "no-new-func": 2,
    "no-new-object": 2,
    "no-new-require": 2,
    "no-new-wrappers": 2,
    "no-obj-calls": 2,
    "no-octal": 2,
    "no-octal-escape": 2,
    "no-proto": 2,
    "no-redeclare": 2,
    "no-regex-spaces": 2,
    "no-return-assign": 2,
    "no-self-compare": 2,
    "no-sequences": 2,
    "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,
    "no-spaced-func": 2,
    "no-sparse-arrays": 2,
    "no-this-before-super": 2,
    "no-throw-literal": 2,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
    "no-undef": 2,
    "no-undef-init": 2,
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
    "no-unneeded-ternary": [
      2,
      { "defaultAssignment": false }
    ],
    "no-unreachable": 2,
    "no-unused-vars": [
      2,
      {
        "vars": "all",
        "args": "none"
      }
    ],
    "no-useless-call": 2,
    "no-with": 2,
    "one-var": [
      2,
      { "initialized": "never" }
    ],
    "operator-linebreak": [
      2,
      "after",
      {
        "overrides": {
          "?": "before",
          ":": "before"
        }
      }
    ],
    "padded-blocks": [ 2, "never" ],
    "quotes": [ 2, "single" ],
    "radix": 2,
    "semi": [ 2, "always" ],
    "semi-spacing": [
      2,
      {
        "before": false,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "space-before-blocks": [ 2, "always" ],
    "space-before-function-paren": [ 2, "always" ],
    "space-in-parens": [ 2, "never" ],
    "space-infix-ops": 2,
    "space-unary-ops": [
      2,
      {
        "words": true,
        "nonwords": false
      }
    ],
    "spaced-comment": [
      2,
      "always",
      { "markers": [ "global", "globals", "eslint", "eslint-disable", "*package", "!", "," ] }
    ],
    "use-isnan": 2,
    "valid-typeof": 2,
    "wrap-iife": [ 2, "any" ],
    "yoda": [ 2, "never" ],

    "standard/object-curly-even-spacing": [ 2, "either" ],
    "standard/array-bracket-even-spacing": [ 2, "either" ],
    "standard/computed-property-even-spacing": [ 2, "even" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't async part of the [ES7 standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Specifications)? For `const` i would expect it to work

Comment: @Icepickle Makes sense, but when i change to `ecmaVersion: 7", eslint stops working entirely, even on plain old JS. There's just no output shown in the Error List window.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296761/how-to-support-es7-in-eslint) work? There they suggest to use babel-eslint instead

Comment: @Icepickle Miracle! Adding the line `"parser": "babel-eslint",` at the top level of `.eslintrc` file worked. Please post this as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: I really don't want to post it as an answer, as I rather see it as a duplicate, feel free to post your own answer if you can add something to the answer given there ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support ES7 in ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296761/how-to-support-es7-in-eslint)